# indexing and more complex approach

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, indexing

For my school I have to create a program which is supposed to index strings. 
I programmed the basic naive approach which is working but I am interested in more efficient ways to solve this problem.
EDIT: I am supposed to index string, vectors of type T and lists of type T.

**Indexing string:**
I use a specialized template for strings.
I started to use [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) which seems to provide better result.And I looked at DAWG.

There is also a given hint in my homework.

> Once indexed, the sequence is searched many times. Therefore, it make
>   sense to spend some time preprocessing the sequence, the searching may
>   be faster. The searching is called approx 100 times per instance.

I don't understand how to use this advice. What do you think?

**Example of input:**

```
Indexclass<string> test ( "aaaaaaau aaauaaaau" );
vector<int> result = test . Index ( "aa" );
 // 0 1 2 3 4 5 9 10 13 14 15

Indexclass <list<string>> test2 ( list<string>{ "hello", "world", "test", "this", "foo", "test", "this", "done" } );
vector<int> r23 = test2 . Index ( list<string>{"test", "this", "foo"} );
// 2
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details on the problem you're trying to solve and perhaps some example input and output?

Comment: what does your `Indexclass::Index()` do?

Comment: for string it is the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm. And otherwise it uses completely naive approach to index the sequence to be indexed. It returns a vector of int containing the position of the corresponding elements inside the sequence.

Comment: so basically you are searching for the exact sequence `{"test", "this", "foo"}`?

Comment: Exactly. And it returns its position in a vector.

Answer (score 1):

The hint means, that you would probably want to use some kind of **sorted container**, in which the insertion of an elements takes more time than in an unsorted container, but when searching the time is constant. As you are inserting each element only once, but searching it around 100 times, this trade would pay off.

But I'd need some more information about what you have already, to make conclusions about what could speed up your code.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand your answer about sorted container.I uptdated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting your input data is one way to speed up the search process by trading preprocessing time. Think about how you search for a number in telephone book. The names in the book are sorted by surname. When I look for a name, I start in the middle and look at one of the names. Now, if the first letter of my name is larger then the name in the middle, I do the same on the right half book, if it is smaller, I go on in the left half. In whatever part of the book I continue, I pick a name in the middle and proceed with the procedure until the name is found. By doing this, you omit half of the current part of the book in every step.

Comment: How can I sort my input data? Is it using binary search? But if the sequence we want is present more than once?

Comment: You can use any sorting algorithm you want for sorting your data. C++ provides an efficient implementation as std::sort. The order of equal elements will be random, but this does not matter for searching. In fact, I would remove duplicates. Binary search is the algorithm I described in my answer, but it is not a sorting algorithm. C++ provides an implementation std::binary_search to check if a sorted range contains an element, and std::lower_bound to actually get an iterator to the element if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so good with C++, so I am giving you an algorithm.

If you  want to search something multiple times, you are looking for a HashMap like structure.
However, when it comes to Strings and you want to index them , you can also look at tries .

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

You can use this structure to create string dictionaries, they support O(1) lookup and also efficient space usage. They also support prefix matching. For example you can input the words JA and find any names that start with JA

From the hint in your question, it looks like you want to search subsequence. For ex you want to find words that have  the words "ake" in them . This can return for ex Jake,Blake but not . In case you want to use this you can use Suffix Tree. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

If you do not understand the description in the wiki link, there are a couple of youtube videos that explain suffix trees usage very well for starters.

Since it is your homework, I will let you decide how you want to implement it